# Connect to Oracle DB using jdbc driver gets stuck while execution

Tags: python, jdbc

I have been trying to connect the Oracle database using jdbc driver and using Timeout function with select Query. After using the timeout the current connection is not getting closed and coming out.

Please find the code being used below :

```
def OracleQuery(dbinput):
    import jaydebeapi
    import jpype
    import threading
    def execute_query(conn, query, event):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        event.set()
    timeout_seconds = 10
    driver_path = r"D:\\diver\Oracle_Jdbc\ojdbc8.jar"
    conn_string = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8022/database"
    username = "XXXXXX"
    password = "XXXXXXXXX"
    jpype.startJVM("-Djava.class.path={}".format(driver_path))
    conn = jaydebapi.connect("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", conn_string, [username, password])
    if conn:
        print("Success")
    query_complete_event = threading.Event()
    def timeout():
        if not query_complete_event.is_set():
            print("Query execution timed out")
            conn.close()
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout_seconds, timeout)
    query = "Select * from Table_Name Where *******"
    try:
        timer.start()
        execute_query(conn, query, query_complete_event)
    finally:
        timer.cancel()
        if query_complete_event.is_set():
            print("Successfully Completed")
```

After using Timeout function the script gets stuck at "conn.close()"

Please Suggest the change to be done.